# Resizing Photoshop artboards since 2017 update

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, cc-2017

Since updating to Photoshop CC 2017 I seem to have lost the ability to resize artboards by clicking and dragging on the edges.

It used to just allow me to do this if I clicked on the artboard name in the layers panel, or selected the artboard selection tool.

Is there a setting for this that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new **Artboard tool** that you can get to by long clicking on the Move tool. Once you've selected the Artboard tool you can hovering over your artboard's edges to get resize handles.